# Python module import (Why does this work ?)

Tags: python, import, directory-structure

As I'm beginning with python language, I want to be able to structure my project directory to keep the work clear and clean with behave test framework.

Here is my basic folder structure:

```
root/
  sample/
    classes/
      simple_class.py
tests/
  features/
    steps/
      simple_class_test.py
```

In my script simple_class_test.py I noticed that I was able to code this:

```
from sample.classes.simple_class import SimpleClass

@Given('I have a simple class')
def i_have_a_simple_class(context):
  context.simpleClass = SimpleClass()
```

That code is functional when I use the command `behave` but despite my
researches on import and modules I am unable to tell how and why the `from sample.classes.simple_class...` is working.

Could you please help me to understand?

Edit: I noticed that the `behave` command works when I launched it from the root directory.
If I launch the command from the `root\tests` directory it fail with an Exception ModuleNotFoundError which seems to be logic.

So I may ask how to allow my tests to find classes they will tests?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Thanks for your link, i did read this documentation before asking but it didn't help me to understand

Comment: That article explains it in much greater detail than any answer could without basically being a copy/paste.  I'd suggest re-reading it.  If your script is located in `root`, then it's using relative paths when resolving the module.

Comment: It depends where you execute from. If you execute from root, the current working directory is scanned whenever you call import (same as any packages that you might have installed using pip install or similar). Since sample is a module in root/, it can be imported. Since it isnt't im tests/ when you execute from there as your working directory, it won't be able to find the module

Comment: After re-reading the doc and based my thoughts on @Karl comment i guess that the method addsitedir() from module site  may be an answer for a dev environment.
One may be able to set an environment variable of the directory containing expected classes and use addsitedir() before any tests could be run.
Could it be a good idea ?

Comment: I'm not even sure what addsitedir() does. But generally, if you want to add a directory to the PYTHONPATH, you would use sys.path.append(...)